# Is there a way to smooth objects / models in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, 3d, render

I am currently trying to smooth my obj model in swift, either using SCNGeometry or MDLMesh is applicable.

I have found the official document showing that there is "subdivisionLevel" property which is for subdivisioning and smoothing in SCNGeometry. However, it is not working as expected.

For level = 1-2, nothing changes apparently

For level = 3-5, still nothing changes apparently but the app is lagging

The below are screenshots of my experiments and codes, is there anything more that I could try to smooth?

subdivisionLevel=0:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFz7V.jpg

subdivisionLevel=5:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8baa.jpg

(As you can see, sharp edges waist and arms are still there)

code:

```
//load obj
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "model_longshirt", ofType: "obj")!
let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
let asset = MDLAsset(url: fileUrl)
guard let object = asset.object(at: 0) as? MDLMesh else {
    fatalError("ERROR_FAILED_TO_GET_MESH_FROM_ASSET")
}

//load material
let scatteringFunction = MDLScatteringFunction()
let material = MDLMaterial(name: "baseMaterial2", scatteringFunction: scatteringFunction)
let texPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "model_LongSleeve_texture_3", ofType: "jpg")!
let texUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: texPath)
let materialProperty = MDLMaterialProperty(name: "baseTexture2", semantic: MDLMaterialSemantic.baseColor, url: texUrl)
material.setProperty(materialProperty)

//attach to node
let scnGeometry = SCNGeometry(mdlMesh: object)
scnGeometry.subdivisionLevel = 5
objNode = SCNNode(geometry: scnGeometry)
objNode.geometry?.firstMaterial = scnMaterial
```

Any help or hint would be appreciative. Thanks.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I finally loaded another model which is smoother.

Comment: What I felt is that Scenekit is doinf face normal calculation instead of vertex based which is causing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If your imported mesh has faces that do not share edges, then you'll get sharp creases as in your screenshot.

```
A    B     C   A    BC   D
+----+-----+   +----+----+
|    |     |   |    |    |
+----+-----+   +----+----+
D    E     F   E    FG   H
```

The mesh on the left will be smooth since the two quads share an edge, the one on the right won't, since the two quads have their own interior edge.